# Build.Vnext TFS2015 is not building solution in "Project Build Order"

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

Has anyone experienced TFS Build 2015 V.Next building their projects in a different order than they set in the sln? We have a project that uses an exe that is created and we have set in the solution to build in a specific order. However when the build runs online it builds in it's own order and the file doesn't exist yet. Obviously I might switch it to be in two solutions but I would rather not have to modify the sln because of a nuance in tfs 2015.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out that the solution didn't support multiple processors because it built a file that it used as a .exe in the build steps. So it built the .exe in another process and then built the other .dll in another process.

Run msbuild with the following argument to resolve the issue:

```
msbuild.exe /m:1 {SLN}
```